# Laravel 5 - SimplePaginate Function is not working here?

Tags: php, function, collections, laravel-5

The Function `simplePaginate()` is working after calling the `where()` Function directly like that :

```
$posts = $userA->Posts()->simplePaginate(10)->get();
```

The Posts() Function in the User Eloquent:

```
public function Posts(){
  return Post::where('user_id','$this->id')->where('category','programming');
}
```

For yet everything is working fine but the problem is when I have more than a user, So I made this :

```
//Creating Empty Collection (Working Without any problem)
$posts = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

//Getting and Adding the userA Posts (Working Without any problem)
$userA_Posts = $userA->Posts();
$posts = $posts->merge($userA_Posts);

//Getting and Adding the userB Posts (Working Without any problem)
$userB_Posts = $userB->Posts();
$posts = $posts->merge($userB_Posts);

//Getting and Adding the userC Posts (Working Without any problem)
$userC_Posts = $userC->Posts();
$posts = $posts->merge($userC_Posts);

//Here Laravel Shows me an ERROR {Method simplePaginate does not exist}
$posts = $posts->sortByDesc('created_at')->simplePaginate(10)->values()->all();

//I changed it to this, ERROR {Method simplePaginate does not exist}
$posts = $posts->sortByDesc('created_at')->values()->simplePaginate(10)->all();

//I changed it to this, ERROR {Method simplePaginate does not exist}
$posts = $posts->sortByDesc('created_at')->values()->all()->simplePaginate(10);
```

> In the [laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections) I didn't find the `simplePaginate()`
>   Function But it's working after the `where()` Function , So please
>   Help

Answer (score 8):

you have to remove `->get()`, leave only `->simplePaginate(10);`